# Accessibility - voiceover not working in swipeviewitems within a bindablelayout - Xamarin.forms iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, swipeview

The UI and commands are working fine both in iOS and android. But the accessibility Voice over is not working in iOS.. Also the talkback is working fine for both the swipeitems in Android.

```
 <SwipeView>
        <SwipeView.RightItems>
            <SwipeItems>
                <SwipeItem Text="Favorite"
                           IconImageSource="favorite.png"
                           BackgroundColor="LightGreen"
                           Command="{Binding Command1}" />
                <SwipeItem Text="Delete"
                           IconImageSource="delete.png"
                           BackgroundColor="LightPink"
                           Command="{Binding Command2}"/>
            </SwipeItems>
        </SwipeView.RightItems>
        <!-- Content -->
        <Grid HeightRequest="60"
              WidthRequest="300"
              BackgroundColor="LightGray">
            <Label Text="Swipe right"
                   HorizontalOptions="Center"
                   VerticalOptions="Center" />
        </Grid>
    </SwipeView>
```

Comment: Hi, what's the iOS device you tested for this, and what's the version of it？

Comment: I tested in iphone7  
software version 14.3

Comment: Okey, you could submit it as an [issue](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/new/choose) here in Github. Then you could follow it up there.